# How to check substring in bash

Tags: bash, apache

Looking into some similar questions here, but still stuck. What is wrong with my code?

```
check_conf_result=$(apachectl configtest 2>&1)
echo "Result of checking apache config: $check_conf_result"

if [[ "$check_conf_result" == *"Syntax OK"* ]]; then
        echo "Reload apache config"
        invoke-rc.d apache2 reload
else
        echo "Apache configure files wrong."
        #exit 1
fi
```

The output is:

```
Result of checking apache config: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
Syntax OK
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mybash.postinst: 114: [: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
Syntax OK: unexpected operator
Apache configure files wrong.
```

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

The following piece of codes works. **But still wonder why the above piece of codes does not work??? (By the way, this is part of debian/mybash.postinst)**. By searching "[[: not found", I found that I should use "#!/bin/bash" if I use "if [[ "$check_conf_result" == *"Syntax OK"* ]]; then". Finally, I used case statement below.

```
        case "$check_conf_result" in
                *Syntax[[:space:]]OK*)
                echo "Reload apache config"
                invoke-rc.d apache2 reload
                ;;
                *)
                echo "Apache config files wrong."
                exit 1
                ;;
        esac
```

Comment: Do a hexdump on `check_conf_result`?  Make sure `Syntax OK` uses a space, not a tab?

Comment: @Mr.Llama yes. also tried [[:space:]]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In bash, the single square bracket doesn't perform pattern matching. In order to use it, you have to use double square brackets:

```
if [[ "$check_conf_result" == *"Syntax OK"* ]] ; then
```

This is documented in `man bash`:

> ```
> string1 == string2
> string1 = string2
> ```
>
> True if the strings are equal.  `=` should be used  with  the  test  command  for
>                 POSIX conformance.  When used with the `[[` command, this performs pattern matching as described above (*Compound Commands*).

Tested:

```
#!/bin/bash
check_conf_result="Result of checking apache config: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
Syntax OK"

if [[ "$check_conf_result" == *"Syntax OK"* ]] ; then
    echo Matches.
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

No idea why choroba's answer can not work in my case at beginning. Confused for some time. Now, I found that  "#!/bin/sh" is the shebang line in my script. If I changed it to "#!/bin/bash", his answer works. Accepted his answer.

Already solved the problem by the following code (also in my update), because I would not like to replace /bin/sh with /bin/bash:

```
case "$check_conf_result" in
        *Syntax[[:space:]]OK*)
        echo "Reload apache config"
        invoke-rc.d apache2 reload
        ;;
        *)
        echo "Apache config files wrong."
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```